# Automate Google Chrome installation on 14.04

Tags: 14.04, bash, google-chrome

Is there a way to completely automate Google Chrome installation on a new machine? I have the following commands working in a bash script:

```
cd /tmp
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
rm -f google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

But I still have to interact with the installation process when Chrome asks to be standard browser and whether to send crash reports or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has a configuration directory, `~/.config/google-chrome` where it stores the settings - including whether it has been run for the first time or not. So you could:

- create an base configuration directory, by copying the existing config directory elsewhere and setting it up a blank one as you want, and then have it copied to the computer on which it is Chrome is being installed - this may have issues if the machines have are very different.
- Create a blank directory and file to fool it into thinking it has already been run for the first time:

  ```
  mkdir $HOME/.config/google-chrome
  touch "$HOME/.config/google-chrome/First Run"
  ```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. By making the directory and touching the `First Run` file, Chrome was silently installed.

Comment: your welcome - all `touch` does is create a blank file at the location you ask it to use.

Comment: I might be new with Linux in general and Ubuntu in particular, but I new about `touch` already - until I learned about `touch` though I used `nano file`, entered a space and saved that file -_-

Comment: I did stuff like that as well :) - you could probably use `echo "" > "$HOME/.config/google-chrome/First Run"` also.